# htaccess redirect everything to folder, except subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I have a /static_site folder.
This folder should be the main site.

And then I have
wp.example.com, which is the Wordpress Site that generates the /static_site

And also another site
another.example.com.

How do I configure this, if request is direct to http(s)://example.com, then rewrite to https://example.com/static_site/.
If the request is wp.example.com or another.example.com, then don't rewrite.

Also, i don't know why, but apperently my currrent .htaccess removes www and adds ssl, which is ok to continue to work like this.

My current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 

    # all to https/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
    RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    
    # root to /static_site
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static_site
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static_site/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've added these two RewriteCond before the RewriteRule, but now I'm getting 503, 403, and 404 on example.com, wp.example.com and another.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =!wp.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =!another.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static_site/$1 [L]
```

EDIT, based on CBroe comment, ended up with

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# https no www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# / to /static_site except subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static_site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static_site/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You will need a RewriteCond checking on the content of %{HTTP_HOST} before that rule as well then. _"Tried to add [...] but [...]"_ - don't just tell us that you failed, but _show us_ what you actually tried.

Comment: Updated what I have tested. Could you please add the full code to check the HTTP_HOST?

Comment: You tried to check `%{REQUEST_URI}`, which is _not_ the host name.

Comment: You said you only want to rewrite, when the host name is `example.com` - so you should rather use _one_ condition that checks it is exactly that, than multiple conditions that check it is _not_ something else. (Multiple RewriteCond are joined by an implicit AND by default, which in combination with _negated_ conditions makes things more complex.)

Comment: Thanks mate, with your comments I got it working. Updated the question with the final result.